# C++ sort 2d vector by column

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, 2d

Can someone tell me the best way to sort a 2d vector by column in C++ without using boost.  I've done some searching and I can't find a good answer.

Thanks

Comment: Presumably you have a 'vector of vectors'. Which vector is your column, the inner one or the outer one? It makes a big difference. Also what is your sort criterion?

Comment: Its a 3x3 vector where I am pushing an 1x3 vector onto the outer vector 3 times.  They are vectors of ints so I'm just trying to sort by the 2nd column in descending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this, I have to make assumptions, meaning you could have given us more information.

Assumption 1: What you call "2D vector" is a vector of vectors, e.g. a `vector<vector<int>>`.

Assumption 2a: the inner vectors are the rows, which means, you want to sort the outer vector by e.g. the second element of its inner vectors. In that case [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) kicks in, which has an overload that takes a comparator as its third argument. The only thing you have to do is to write a comparator (i.e. a function, function object, lambda etc.), that takes two vectors and compares them by their N-th element. Should not be too hard.

Assumption 2b: the inner vectors are the *columns*, i.e. you want to sort one of the inner vectors and apply the reorderings to each other row as well. That's a bit more complicated, e.g. you could make another vector of indices 0 through N and sort that with a comparator that, given two indices `i` and `j` compares them by actually comparing `column[i]` and `column[j]`. After you have sorted that vector, you can accordingly reorder all the columns.

Comment: 2a applies to me.  Thanks, I'll try it

Comment: yep works. I just used the comparator function bool myfunction (vector<int> i,vector<int> j) { return (i[2]<j[2]); }

Answer (score 1):

The sort() Function in STL can do it for you. You just need to write a function to compare 2 cases in your vector.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

After, it depends the type of sort you need, you can sort the columns one by one, then the first row.

Comment: I'm not sure to follow you, can you give us the code of your vector declaration, and when you add data into ?